# Swift - Shadow for a irregular shape of a View

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, shadow

i am struggling to add shadow to a custom shape.

Here is a picture of what i want to construct:
[image]
(Dont mind the text and the symbol)

You can see the custom shape with the curved corner on the right and the rectangular shape on the left with shadow.
I am using UIView, and added corner to the left.

This is the code i have so far that shape the view correct:

```
 View1.backgroundColor = .green //green color is just to see the shape well
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:View1.bounds,
                            byRoundingCorners:[.topRight, .bottomRight],
                            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: self.frame.height/2, height:  self.frame.height/2))

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
```

I Have tried to add shadow to it, but the shadow does not apear.
Here is the code i have tried to add shadow:

```
    View1.layer.masksToBounds = false
    View1.layer.layer.shadowPath = maskLayer.path
    View1.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    View1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 3.0)
    View1.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    View1.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
```

How can you add shadow to this shape?

Comment: There's a bit of a decision about this online, but you might need to look around a bit. The "solution" which seems to be mostly used too use two views, one which is masked and one which is shadowed

Comment: Please remove clips to bound property. and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a single UIView (shadowView), adding a shapeLayer sublayer and setting the shadow of the shadowView's layer.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
    }
    
    @IBOutlet var shadowView: UIView!
    func setup() {
        // setup irregular shape
        let path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: shadowView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize.init(width: 20, height: 20))
        let layer = CAShapeLayer.init()
        layer.frame = shadowView.bounds
        layer.path = path.cgPath
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        shadowView.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)

        // setup shadow
        shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 8
        shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0, height: 2.5)
        shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shadowView.layer.shadowPath = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

Note:

1. The `shadowView.clipToBounds` must be `false` for the shadows to take effect.
2. To see the `layer.fillColor`, set the `shadowView.backgroundColor` to `.clear`.

   You can easily achieve the above via Interface Builder by setting the 'Background' property and unchecking the 'Clip to Bounds' checkbox.

Comment: Perfect explanation! Works like a charm! Thanks